Panic trace in igc driver in kernel 5.15.0-101 - Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Panic trace in igc driver in kernel 5.15.0-101 - Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
When huge io is transfer my system get hung after debugged found that intel igc driver is causing the issue . I am using ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with kernel 5.15.0-101. below mentioned the print for reference. Is there any solution to avoid this hung issue OR any latest kernel version this got solved. Kindly help me to solve this issue.
Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653285] ------------[ cut here ]------------

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653291] NETDEV WATCHDOG: ETH04 (igc): transmit queue 3 timed out

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653319] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:477 dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653333] Modules linked in: ipt_NETFLOW(OE) xt_nat xfrm_user xt_MASQUERADE cfg80211 bonding tls ip_set_hash_mac xt_TCPMSS xt_connbytes xt_hl xt_bpf nf_conntrack_netlink xt_DSCP xt_recent xt_LOG nf_log_syslog xt_hashlimit xt_state xt_conntrack xt_pkttype xt_tcpudp xt_multiport xt_comment ip_set_hash_netiface xt_connmark xt_mark nft_chain_nat xt_set nft_counter xt_CT nft_compat ip_set_hash_net ip_set nf_tables nfnetlink wireguard curve25519_x86_64 libchacha20poly1305 chacha_x86_64 poly1305_x86_64 libcurve25519_generic libchacha ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel ip6_tables xt_ndpi(OE) br_netfilter bridge stp llc nf_nat_tftp nf_nat_pptp nf_nat_irc nf_nat_sip nf_nat_ftp nf_nat_h323 nf_nat nf_conntrack_tftp nf_conntrack_pptp nf_conntrack_irc nf_conntrack_sip nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack_h323 nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 sunrpc binfmt_misc snd_sof_pci_intel_apl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653420]  snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio intel_rapl_msr snd_soc_skl ee1004 snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core intel_rapl_common snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp intel_pmc_bxt intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi coretemp snd_soc_core snd_compress snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm_intel ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 snd_hda_intel sha1_ssse3 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec rapl intel_cstate snd_hda_core snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm snd_timer snd mei_me i2c_i801 mei i2c_smbus soundcore sch_fq_codel dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 raid10 raid456 libcrc32c async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor xor async_tx raid6_pq raid1 raid0 multipath linear mmc_block nvme nvme_core mpt3sas raid_class mptsas mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_sas

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653490]  virtio_scsi virtio_blk virtio_net net_failover failover ixgbe xfrm_algo mdio ixgb igb dca usbhid hid_generic hid nls_iso8859_1 overlay i915 i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops aesni_intel cec crypto_simd cryptd rc_core ahci xhci_pci mac_hid xhci_pci_renesas psmouse drm igc libahci video [last unloaded: ipt_NETFLOW]

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653525] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Tainted: G           OE     5.15.0-101-generic #111


Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653528] Hardware name: Default string Default string/QGLK03, BIOS QGLK0301.V10 07/05/2023

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653530] RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653535] Code: eb 97 48 8b 5d d0 c6 05 de cf 67 01 01 48 89 df e8 8e 5e f9 ff 44 89 e1 48 89 de 48 c7 c7 90 d2 2d a2 48 89 c2 e8 d4 d5 19 00 <0f> 0b eb 80 e9 01 70 23 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 57 41 56

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653537] RSP: 0018:ffffaf770016ce70 EFLAGS: 00010282

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653539] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9e5908672000 RCX: 0000000000000027

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653541] RDX: ffff9e597bda0588 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9e597bda0580

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653543] RBP: ffffaf770016cea8 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: fffffffffffea2c8

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653544] R10: ffffffffa3e5fa40 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000003

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653546] R13: ffff9e5908678c40 R14: 0000000000000004 R15: ffff9e59086724c0

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653548] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9e597bd80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653550] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653551] CR2: 000056236015c000 CR3: 0000000130610000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653554] Call Trace:

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653557]  <IRQ>

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653561]  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1d6/0x2ea

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653566]  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1d6/0x2ea

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653569]  ? call_timer_fn+0x29/0x120

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653574]  ? show_regs.part.0+0x23/0x29

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653577]  ? show_regs.cold+0x8/0xd

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653580]  ? dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653582]  ? __warn+0x8c/0x100

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653585]  ? dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653589]  ? report_bug+0xa4/0xd0

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653594]  ? handle_bug+0x39/0x90

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653598]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x19/0x70

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653600]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653604]  ? dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653607]  ? pfifo_fast_enqueue+0x160/0x160

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653610]  call_timer_fn+0x29/0x120

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653612]  __run_timers.part.0+0x1e3/0x270

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653615]  ? ktime_get+0x43/0xc0

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653618]  ? lapic_next_deadline+0x2c/0x40

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653622]  ? clockevents_program_event+0xaa/0x130

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653627]  run_timer_softirq+0x2a/0x60

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653629]  __do_softirq+0xd6/0x2e7

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653632]  irq_exit_rcu+0x94/0xc0

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653635]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x80/0x90

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653638]  </IRQ>

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653639]  <TASK>

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653640]  

asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1b/0x20

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653643] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xd9/0x620

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653647] Code: 3d 7c 5c 98 5e e8 a7 59 67 ff 49 89 c7 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 ff e8 e8 66 67 ff 80 7d d0 00 0f 85 61 01 00 00 fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 f6 0f 88 6d 01 00 00 4d 63 ee 49 83 fd 09 0f 87 e7 03 00 00

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653649] RSP: 0018:ffffaf77000c7e28 EFLAGS: 00000246

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653651] RAX: ffff9e597bdb14c0 RBX: ffff9e597bdbc700 RCX: 0000000000000000

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653653] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000002 RDI: 0000000000000000

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653654] RBP: ffffaf77000c7e78 R08: 00020216bdfa8ffd R09: 00000000000249f0

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653656] R10: 0000000000000008 R11: 071c71c71c71c71c R12: ffffffffa2cd6e80

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653657] R13: 0000000000000002 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: 00020216bdfa8ffd

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653660]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xc8/0x620

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653663]  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x50

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653665]  cpuidle_idle_call+0x142/0x1e0

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653669]  do_idle+0x83/0xf0

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653671]  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653673]  start_secondary+0x12a/0x180

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653676]  
secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653682]  </TASK>

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653683] ---[ end trace c7a547b27861e8ba ]---

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653837] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: Register Dump

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653839] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: Register Name   Value

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653860] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: CTRL            081c0641

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653864] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: STATUS          00380683

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653867] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: CTRL_EXT        100000c0

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653870] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: MDIC            181e8877

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653872] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: ICR             00000081

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653875] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: RCTL            04408022

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653882] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: RDLEN[0-3]      00001000 00001000 00001000 00001000

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653889] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: RDH[0-3]        00000083 00000016 00000001 00000099

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653897] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: RDT[0-3]        00000082 00000015 00000000 00000098

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653904] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: RXDCTL[0-3]     02040808 02040808 02040808 02040808

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653912] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: RDBAL[0-3]      4f4d9000 073db000 4de47000 0b2cc000

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653919] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: RDBAH[0-3]      00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653922] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: TCTL            a503f0fa

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653929] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: TDBAL[0-3]      094cc000 4d67d000 4f4da000 06cb7000

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653968] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: TDBAH[0-3]      00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.653994] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: TDLEN[0-3]      00001000 00001000 00001000 00001000

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.654001] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: TDH[0-3]        00000080 00000029 00000084 000000a9

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.654008] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: TDT[0-3]        00000080 00000029 00000084 000000a9

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.654015] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: TXDCTL[0-3]     02100108 02100108 02100108 02100108

Aug 28 15:31:39 Future-CH kernel: [565246.654018] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: Reset adapter

Aug 28 15:31:42 Future-CH kernel: [565250.013965] igc 0000:05:00.0 ETH04: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
    


After the update that gave you 22.04.4 over 22.04.3 did you change the kernel? It should have given you a 6.8 series kernel.

i have changed the kernel right now its 22.04.4

What are you talking about? 22.04 is a version of the Ubuntu OS not a kernel version.
